# semantic-ui-react - form input placeholder position

Tags: css, input, placeholder, semantic-ui-react

I'm using the components from `semantic-ui-react` to display a `Field` and `Button` like below:

```
<Segment clearing>
    <Form>
        <Form.Group style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <Form.Field style={{ flexGrow: "1" }}>
                <Form.Input
                    placeholder="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
                    focus
                />
            </Form.Field>

            <Form.Button
                    color="green"
                    floated="right"
                    content="Add new API key"
                    type='submit'
            />
        </Form.Group>
    </Form>
</Segment>
```

Nothing incredibly fancy, the result is as below:

[image]

I want to reposition the `placeholder` in the `Form.Input` to the right side like below:

[image]

How exactly can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the CSS placeholder selector. You could, for example, give the Form.Input component an arbitrary class such as "input-aligned-end" and then style it in CSS:

```
.input-aligned-end::placeholder {
  text-align: end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try this

```
labelPosition='right'
```

style

```
style={{
        paddingLeft: "50%"
   }}
```